# Как посмотреть статистику использования геокодера за 2015-2016

Tags: yandex-maps-api, статистика

Проблема в том, что в интерфейсе при изменении одной из дат происходит сразу загрузка данных. При этом, если выбрать дату окончания периода меньше даты начала, то выводится страница с отсутствием результата, при этом поля дат убираются.
Если же выбирать период больше года, страница просто не загружается, а выводится сообщение "Произошла ошибка, попробуйте обновить страницу".
Единственный возможный вариант, это отодвигать рассматриваемый период по одному месяцу в прошлое, что очень не удобно.

Comment: Непонятно, о каком именно сервисе вопрос. Выглядит как багрепорт/фичреквест к какой-то админке. Такие вопросы стоит направлять сразу техподдержке сервиса. На SO могут помочь только с техническими вопросами.

Comment: Да, согласен, это скорее вопрос к техподдержке, на тот момент думал, что может есть какие-либо еще варианты, например через API. Но ни чего не нашел.
Отчасти это админка - интерфейс просмотра статистики использования API яндекса в отношении карт.

Comment: API для сбора статистики нету